# How do you enable a disabled radio button using jquery in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

This works in Firefox.  How can I make it work in IE7?

```
$( '#addressSection input:radio' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
```

I've also tried these to no avail:

```
$( '#addressSection input:radio' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );

$( '#addressSection input:radio' ).attr( 'disabled', 'false' );

$( '#addressSection input:radio' ).attr( {disabled: false} );

$( '#addressSection input:radio' ).attr( {disabled: 'false'} );
```

Here's the radio button html as it is rendered by IE7.  The original is written in Spring and custom tags.

```
<div id="addressSection">
  <div class="column">
    <ul class="simpleForm">
      <li>
        <input id="addressUseUorA" name="addressUseUorA" value="U" type="radio" type="text" value=""/>
        <label for="addressUseUorA">Use User Address</label>
        <input id="addressUseUorA" name="addressUseUorA" value="A" type="radio" type="text" value=""/>
        <label for="addressUseUorA">Use Account Address</label>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Here's what was causing the issue.

I disabled the field like this, trying to disable all fields in the DIV:

```
$( '#addressSection' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
```

This causes an issue in ie7, but not firefox.

The issue was resolved when I changed the disable code to:

```
$( '#addressSection input' ).attr( 'disabled', true);
```

my guess is that the disable attribute was applied to the div and not the field and so could not be removed by referencing the radio button.

Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Can you post the HTML, maybe it will help?

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 elements with the same id.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

did you try:

```
$( '#addressSection input[type="radio"]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
```

Comment: This is not working.  I have put this line directly below it and it is working correctly:  $('#addressSection input[type=radio]').hide();

Comment: @Kevin, can you show what `$( '#addressSection input[type="radio"]' ).attr( "disabled" );` after you supposedly enabled it?

Comment: $( '#addressSection input[type="radio"]' ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" ); Give the attribute the "disabled" value.

Comment: @Brad, why would the OP disable it again?

Comment: The value of `$( '#addressSection input[type="radio"]' ).attr( "disabled" );` is false after this line.

Comment: @Kevin, if it is disabled, what is the issue?

Comment: @Neal, The problem is the field is not showing enabled to the user.  It's still disabled on the screen.

Comment: as @Rocket said in the comments, can you post the HTML as well or post it on jsfiddle so we can see the same thing you are seeing?

Comment: @Neal, My html is posted.  As @Mohammed-ElSayed has shown the jquery works in most cases.  Since this is the case, I have looked at other jquery actions taken on the fields to determine if they could have adverse effects on the radio button.  Before my remove disable is attempted, I do a .hide on the field and then call toggle.  Could either of these cause strange behavior in IE7?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#addressSection input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just give it a test on JsFiddle and looks like `removeAttr` is working just fine on chrome/FF/IE7.

here is the live sample link: http://jsfiddle.net/2GpyQ/1/

let me know if it worked for you, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different ID for input elements.
This code is working:

```
<div id="addressSection"> <div class="column"> 
    <ul class="simpleForm"> 
        <li> 
            <form>
            <input id="addressUseUorA1" name="addressUseUorA" value="U" type="radio" type="text" disabled="disabled" value=""/> 
            <label for="addressUseUorA1">Use User Address</label> 
            <input id="addressUseUorA2" name="addressUseUorA" value="A" type="radio" type="text" value=""/> 
            <label for="addressUseUorA2">Use Account Address</label> 
            </form>
            <a href="#">click</a>
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</div> </div>
<script>
$('#addressSection a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $( '#addressSection input[type="radio"]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
});
</script>
```