# Should I write jquery for all diffrent browsers a customer may use?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

Referring to this question

[How do you enable a disabled radio button using jquery in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5641380/675587)

I have been writing a different Css file for each browser separately. I have just one common jquery file now in my project and it works in Firefox well, should I code one for my chrome and IE too ?

Comment: Can you try just using javascript without jquery and see if that works.  i.e.
document.getElementById('addressSection').disabled = false;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is compatible with all the major browsers so whatever code works in ff should work in chrome and IE.  Because of this you shouldn't have to write separate code for each browser.

http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility

Comment: You nailed it: the whole _point_ of jQuery is cross-browser JavaScript.

Comment: No problem, glad you could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

jQuery is designed to be cross browser compatible.  See : http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility

> jQuery actively supports these
>   browsers:
>
> ```
> * Firefox 2.0+
> * Internet Explorer 6+
> * Safari 3+
> * Opera 10.6+
> * Chrome 8+
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above. JQuery for the most part works across all browsers.
As a side note you shouldn't have to write different css files for each browser. Maybe some small helper files to make adjustments but not full files for each browser.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't. jQuery supports all major versions of all major browsers.
Even if some behavior isn't available in older browsers(e.g. localStorage), you should use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to smooth out any problems.

Which, if you're only using jQuery, you shouldn't have in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to use a small amount of browser specific code as jQuery works similar with all browsers but not the same always.